# Linq Query with Join not working on .Net 3.5 but works on .Net 4+

Tags: linq, join, lambda

My query was working in .Net 3.5 SP1 until I added a join.  The join was put in place to allow selection from the Comments entity even when there was no associated User entity.  I get the following error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[XXX.YYY.BusinessLayer.User] DefaultIfEmpty[User](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[XXX.YYY.BusinessLayer.User])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I verified the query works in .Net 4+ (I think!) using LinqPad.

My query in the solution is as follows:

```
var comments = (from dic in _context.Comments
                        join u in _context.Users on dic.CommentUserId equals u.UserId into j1
                        from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where dic.Parent.Id == 406
                        select new { dic.CommentId, dic.CommentDate, dic.CommentText, j2.AccountName }).AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(x => new CommentInfo
                       {
                           CommentId = x.CommentId,
                           CommentDate = x.CommentDate,
                           CommentText = x.CommentText,
                           UserName = ActiveDirectoryUtil.GetUserDisplayName(x.AccountName)
                       });
```

I am still new to Linq and Lambda so still finding my way around things.  ActiveDirectoryUtil.GetUserDisplayName is a static method call to do a lookup to get a user's display name.

The issue came around after adding the following lines:

```
... into j1 
from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework in.NET 3.5 Framework does not support `DefaultIfEmpty()` method.

Comment: Hi Emre...  I got that now.  I had to change the way in which I do the query.